# Creating a generic list iterator in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to wrap a list of items, but I want the flexibility of supplying a unique template.

```
<list [items]="someItems">
    <book-list-item><!-- Books, cars, dogs, whatever -->
    </book-list-item><!-- This will contain a unique template -->
</list>
```

**ListItemComponent**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'list-item',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
            <ng-content></ng-content><!-- Whatever book-list-item contains -->
        </div>`
})
export class ListItemComponent {
    @Input() items: Array<any>;
}
```

**BookListItemComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'book-list-item',
    template: `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">Books</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">Rule</div>
        </div>`

})
export class BookListItemComponent {}
```

Obviously I'd be passing books as *items*, but this is just an example. I can get something similar to this working, but "Books Rule" only prints out in the last list-group-item (because Bootstrap).

I'm really looking to understand how to pass a generic component to parent component that will iterate over the generic component as an item in a list of items. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](https://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html). It does something very similar to what you need. Your main challange will be binding the values. You can also Look at [Ben Nadel's article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3101-experimenting-with-dynamic-template-rendering-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm). It relates to RC1 and even he in the comments mentions that the setLocal is not there anymore and that you need to pass the context.